# ASP.NET MVC - Is a ViewModel an appropriate place to do minor calculations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm working on a UserViewModel, and I'm wondering if it's appropriate to do minor calculations in the VM, or if I need to separate it further and calculate elsewhere.

```
Public Class UserViewModel
    Public Property UserName As String
    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property Website As String
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property OpenIds As List(Of OpenID)
    Public Property UserAge As String
    Public Property About As String
    Public Property Slug As String
    Public Property LastSeen As String
    Public Property Region As String
    Public Property MemberSince As String
    Public Property Reputation As String
    Public Property isUserMatch As Boolean = False
    Private MarkDownSharp As MarkdownSharp.Markdown

    Public Sub New(ByVal user As User)
        Dim currentuser As Authentication.AuthUserData = Authentication.CustomAuthentication.RetrieveAuthUser
        MarkDownSharp = New MarkdownSharp.Markdown
        With MarkDownSharp
            .AutoHyperlink = False
            .AutoNewLines = True
            .EncodeProblemUrlCharacters = True
            .LinkEmails = True
            .StrictBoldItalic = True
        End With

        _UserName = If(Not user.UserName Is Nothing, user.UserName, "User" & user.ID.ToString)
        _Email = user.Email
        _Website = user.WebSite
        _ID = user.ID
        _OpenIds = user.OpenIDs.ToList
        ''# Converts the users birthdate to an age representation
        ''#      IE: 29
        _UserAge = user.BirthDate.ToAge

        ''# Because some people can be real ass holes and try to submit bad
        ''# data (scripts and shitè) we have to modify the "About" content in
        ''# order to sanitize it.  At the same time, we transform the Markdown
        ''# into valid HTML. The raw input is stored without sanitization in
        ''# the database.  this could mean Javascript injection, etc, so the
        ''# output ALWAYS needs to be sanitized.
        _About = Trim(Utilities.HtmlSanitizer.Sanitize(MarkDownSharp.Transform(user.About)))

        ''# Removes spaces from Usernames in order to properly display the
        ''# username in the address bar
        _Slug = Replace(user.UserName, " ", "-")

        ''# Returns a boolean result if the current logged in user matches the
        ''# details view of the user in question.  This is done so that we can
        ''# show the edit button to logged in users.
        _isUserMatch = If(currentuser.ID = user.ID, True, False)


        ''# Grabs the users registration data and formats it to a time span
        ''# The "timeago-nosuffix" CssClass is there to remove the "ago"
        ''# suffix from the "member for" string. Cuz when you think about
        ''# it... "Member for 5 days ago" just sounds stupid.
        _MemberSince = user.MemberSince.ToTimeSpan("timeago-nosuffix")

        ''# Grabs the users last activity and formats it to a time span
        _LastSeen = user.ActivityLogs.Reverse.FirstOrDefault.ActivityDate.ToTimeSpan("timeago", "ago")

        ''# Formats the users reputation to a comma Deliminated number 
        ''#    IE: 19,000 or 123k
        _Reputation = user.Reputation.ToShortHandNumber


        ''# Get the name of the users current Region.
        _Region = user.Region.Region.FirstOrDefault
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: On a side note. I hate it when people edit the tags without really thinking it through. My example is in VB.NET **BUT** that doesn't mean that my question has anything to do with VB.NET.  The question is about principles, but with a VB.NET tag added, it will keep qualified (NON VB) people from looking at the question. So PLEASE for the love of all things holy, DON'T edit tags to include the code language if the question doesn't rely on on a language specific answer!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If those calculations concern formatting for the given view then it is the exact place. It seems you are doing exactly this: formatting for the view which is OK (sorry if I've missed something, my VB.NET code reading skills start to elude me :-)). If on the other hand it is some domain logic it is probably better suited to the model so that it can be reused.

Comment: Most of what I'm doing is exactly that... formatting.  In my events ViewModel however, I'm also adding all my my "Latitude" / "Longitude" items into a variable and then dividing by the number of records... this way I can dynamically get the center of a Map.  See the first code block (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115180/virtual-earth-bing-maps-calculate-best-zoom-level) - I moved that code to a ViewModel.

Comment: @rockin That doesn't sound minor enough to me.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't disagree with Darin there is another approach.

Instead of putting simple logic into your ViewModels you could also put that logic in whatever layer you use to transform domain model objects into dto or viewmodel objects.  Lets call this your Mapping layer.   This keeps your viewmodels really dumb and flexible while keeping all of the custom view transformation logic in a separate place.

Using a tool such as AutoMapper makes this really easy to do.